# SVN icons have changed to some non-svn related icons

Tags: icons, svn

I have several SVN repositories and up until yesterday the SVN icons were being displayed correctly. Today, some totally unrelated icons have been replaced. The only thing which I did was that Yesterday I installed Google Drive. However it does not seem to me that these are Google Drive related icons neither (see screenshot attached).

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks an in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it TortoiseSVN?

Comment: The icon I see on the screenshot is a default icon for Windows library directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was Google Drive which was messing up the icons due to Window's limitation of context icons.